# Spotify Apps Api - "Share" button for created playlist

Tags: spotify

Is there a way where you could then have a "share this" button that activates the spotify sharing options for a dynamically created playlist that has been added by the user?

You can do it from right clicking the playlist in the spotify left column but it would be good to be able to repeat this functionality from within an app

thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Apps API provides the `showSharePopup()` API which pops up a dialog to share the given URI, like this:

```
var sp = getSpotifyApi(1);
var models = sp.require('sp://import/scripts/api/models');

models.application.showSharePopup(document.getElementById("header"), "spotify:track:6JEK0CvvjDjjMUBFoXShNZ");
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://developer.spotify.com/technologies/apps/docs/beta/2edfee4d46.html).

Comment: thanks for the reply, but this is for albums or tracks, can you do it for playlists created? thanks

Comment: I think a dynamically created playlist you can't as there is no URI

Comment: Do you mean "dynamically created" as in a playlist with no name (i.e., doesn't appear in the user's sidebar) or simply one created in code? If it's the former, they'll never be sharable — if it isn't in the sidebar, it isn't in the backend and nobody else can access it. If it's the latter, you don't get the URI unless the user gives it to you.

Comment: thanks, yes its in the sidebar of the users spotify but was created from a group of albums selected within the APP. So im guessing no way of getting the URI as it contains the users username and this isnt passed to the APP API?

Comment: if you use the datastorage for the current user, I'm quite sure you can do this : `pl = new m.playlist("new playlist"); stor.set("plurishare", pl.uri);`, let us know ?

Comment: forget to put : `stor = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/storage");` and after use the iKenndac script...

Answer (score 0):

I just test my comment and it works, I propose then as an answer :

When you add the playlist to the user store the new uri :

```
stor = sp.require("sp://import/scripts/storage");
```

In the event that add the playlist to user sidebar :

```
pl = new model.playlist("playlist to share");
stor.set("playlisturitoshare", pl.uri);
```

To share then use iKenndac solution

Comment: hey thanks, but the uri is blank (null) when creating playlists?

Comment: I will test again on my side, hope I didn't make a mistake.

Comment: You were right after a new try I got also null in the uri. I don't understand what I did on my first try.